# how can I run node js app when installed node js version is higher and app using old version

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm

I am relatively new to Node js and was working on .NET MVC. When I am trying to run it using command `node index` its giving me an below error.

```html
H:\Services\src>node index
H:\Services\src\index.js:1
import app from './app';
^^^^^^

SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module
?[90m    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:895:18)?[39m
?[90m    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:995:10)?[39m
?[90m    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:815:32)?[39m
?[90m    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:727:14)?[39m
?[90m    at Function.Module.runMain (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1047:10)?[39m
?[90m    at internal/main/run_main_module.js:17:11?[39m
```

Below is my package.json file. It says it is using node version 8.0.0 and npm version 5.0.0. Bt I have installed node version is v12.14.0 and NPM installed version is 6.13.4.

```html
{
  "name": "core",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "description": "Core",
  "main": "dist/index.js",
  "engines": {
    "node": "8.0.0",
    "npm": "5.0.0"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "prestart": "npm run -s build",
    "start": "node dist/index.js",
    "dev": "nodemon src/index.js --exec \"node -r dotenv/config -r babel-register\" localdev",
    "clean": "rimraf dist && rimraf -p",
    "build": "npm run clean && mkdir -p dist && babel src -s -D -d dist",
    "test": "jest --watch",
    "lint": "esw -w src test"
  },
  "keywords": [
    "express",
    "babel",
    "es6",
    "es2015",
    "es2016",
    "es2017",
    "eslint"
  ],
  "author": "ABC",
  "license": "UNLICENSED",
  "dependencies": {
    "babel-cli": "6.26.0",
    "babel-plugin-transform-object-rest-spread": "6.26.0",
    "babel-preset-env": "1.6.1",
    "cors": "2.8.5",
    "express": "4.16.4",
    "js-yaml": "3.12.2",
    "mssql": "5.0.0",
    "winston": "3.1.0",
    "winston-daily-rotate-file": "3.5.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-eslint": "7.2.3",
    "babel-jest": "21.0.2",
    "babel-register": "6.24.1",
    "dotenv": "4.0.0",
    "eslint": "4.10.0",
    "eslint-config-airbnb-base": "12.1.0",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "2.8.0",
    "eslint-plugin-jest": "21.0.2",
    "eslint-watch": "3.1.0",
    "nodemon": "1.18.10",
    "rimraf": "2.6.3"
  },
  "babel": {
    "presets": [
      [
        "env",
        {
          "targets": {
            "node": "current"
          }
        }
      ]
    ],
    "plugins": [
      "transform-object-rest-spread"
    ]
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "parser": "babel-eslint",
    "plugins": [
      "import",
      "jest"
    ],
    "parserOptions": {
      "ecmaVersion": 2017,
      "sourceType": "module"
    },
    "env": {
      "node": true,
      "jest": true
    },
    "extends": [
      "eslint:recommended"
    ]
  }
}
```

I have tried different google solutions for above error but each time gets a diff error depending upon steps I am doing to fix the issue. I am just looking to run this code and test it locally.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Take a look at the "scripts" sections  in your package.json for commands that are intended to run. You start them with `npm run <command>` so in your case you probably want: `npm run dev`

Comment: Your `start` script calls `dist/index.js` file, but you are in `src` folder, go to project root folder and try run script again. Maybe this solves your problem. But you should build your app before running `start` script

Comment: @RolandStarke when I ran  npm run dev, I again got the different error, as below   'nodemon' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! cbl-cafbi-core@0.0.1 dev: `nodemon src/index.js --exec "node -r dotenv/config -r babel-register" localdev`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the cbl-cafbi-core@0.0.1 dev script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

Comment: @AhmetZeybek, in my project structure I dont 'dist' folder itself.

Comment: @Nilesh First install `nodemon` package globally, then run `build` script. After build, you must have a dist folder in your project root folder, you can run `start` script after success build. Anyway, you don't have to install nodemon package for `build` and `start` scripts

Comment: Can you run `npm install` and then `npm run dev` again? (@AhmetZeybek installing nodemon globaly does not seem necessary as its in the "devDependencies". )

Comment: Oh sorry, I didn't look deps... @RolandStarke

Comment: @RolandStarke I have tried to run npm install but again got the error as       npm ERR! code ECONNRESET
npm ERR! errno ECONNRESET
npm ERR! network request to https://registry.npmjs.org/acorn/-/acorn-5.7.3.tgz failed, reason: read ECONNRESET
npm ERR! network This is a problem related to network connectivity.
npm ERR! network In most cases you are behind a proxy or have bad network settings.
npm ERR! network
npm ERR! network If you are behind a proxy, please make sure that the
npm ERR! network 'proxy' config is set properly.  See: 'npm help config'

Comment: @RolandStarke I can see one more problem in my package.json saying - "Problems loading reference 'https://schemastore.azurewebsites.net/schemas/json/package.json': Unable to load schema from 'https://schemastore.azurewebsites.net/schemas/json/package.json': unable to get local issuer certificate. "

Comment: I have resolved above issue from here. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60037937/how-to-resolve-npm-proxy-issue-whilel-running-node-js-application[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60037937/how-to-resolve-npm-proxy-issue-whilel-running-node-js-application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60037937/how-to-resolve-npm-proxy-issue-whilel-running-node-js-application)

Comment: I have resolved above issue using below thread. [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60037937/how-to-resolve-npm-proxy-issue-whilel-running-node-js-application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60037937/how-to-resolve-npm-proxy-issue-whilel-running-node-js-application)