# How to resolve NPM proxy Issue whilel running Node JS application

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, proxy

I have installed Noed JS and NPM. I have cloned the repo from git and trying to run the app in local. But I am facing below proxy issue while running app.

> ```
> npm install nodemon
> npm ERR! code ENOTFOUND
> npm ERR! errno ENOTFOUND
> npm ERR! network request to https://registry.npmjs.com/nodemon failed, reason: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND 28
> npm ERR! network This is a problem related to network connectivity.
> npm ERR! network In most cases you are behind a proxy or have bad network settings.
> npm ERR! network
> npm ERR! network If you are behind a proxy, please make sure that the
> npm ERR! network 'proxy' config is set properly.  See: 'npm help config'`
> ```

I have check with proxy and it is set to below network.

> ```
> Pinging proxy.internal.domainname.com with 32 bytes of data:
> Reply from <ip address="">: bytes=32 time=2ms TTL=247
> Reply from <ip address="">: bytes=32 time=2ms TTL=247
> Reply from <ip address="">: bytes=32 time=2ms TTL=247
> Reply from <ip address="">: bytes=32 time=2ms TTL=247
> Ping statistics for <ip address="">:
> Packets: Sent = 4, Received = 4, Lost = 0 (0% loss),
> Approximate round trip times in milli-seconds:
> Minimum = 2ms, Maximum = 2ms, Average = 2ms
> ```

I tried to set proxy to `https://registry.npmjs.com/nodemon` using below command.

```
npm config set registry "http://registry.npmjs.org/
```

When I run npm install after this, again I got the same error.

> ```
> npm --proxy http://registry.npmjs.org/  install npm
> npm ERR! code ENOTFOUND
> npm ERR! errno ENOTFOUND
> npm ERR! network request to http://registry.npmjs.org/npm failed, reason: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND 28
> npm ERR! network This is a problem related to network connectivity.
> npm ERR! network In most cases you are behind a proxy or have bad network settings.
> npm ERR! network
> npm ERR! network If you are behind a proxy, please make sure that the
> npm ERR! network 'proxy' config is set properly.  See: 'npm help config'`
> ```

I have tried many other workarounds from google but still facing the same proxy issue.
I am just looking to run this app in local so that I can test my code in local before deploying. Am I missing something here.

Below is my sample package.json file.

```
{
  "name": "abc",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "description": "abc",
  "main": "dist/index.js",
  "engines": {
    "node": "8.0.0",
    "npm": "5.0.0"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "prestart": "npm run -s build",
    "start": "node dist/index.js",
    "dev": "nodemon src/index.js --exec \"node -r dotenv/config -r babel-register\" localdev",
    "clean": "rimraf dist && rimraf -p",
    "build": "npm run clean && mkdir -p dist && babel src -s -D -d dist",
    "test": "jest --watch",
    "lint": "esw -w src test"
  },
  "keywords": [
    "express",
    "babel",
    "es6",
    "es2015",
    "es2016",
    "es2017",
    "eslint"
  ],
  "author": "abc",
  "license": "LICENSED",
  "dependencies": {
    "babel-cli": "6.26.0",
    "babel-plugin-transform-object-rest-spread": "6.26.0",
    "babel-preset-env": "1.6.1",
    "cors": "2.8.5",
    "express": "4.16.4",
    "js-yaml": "3.12.2",
    "mssql": "5.0.0",
    "winston": "3.1.0",
    "winston-daily-rotate-file": "3.5.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-eslint": "7.2.3",
    "babel-jest": "21.0.2",
    "babel-register": "6.24.1",
    "dotenv": "4.0.0",
    "eslint": "4.10.0",
    "eslint-config-airbnb-base": "12.1.0",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "2.8.0",
    "eslint-plugin-jest": "21.0.2",
    "eslint-watch": "3.1.0",
    "nodemon": "1.18.10",
    "rimraf": "2.6.3"
  },
  "babel": {
    "presets": [
      [
        "env",
        {
          "targets": {
            "node": "current"
          }
        }
      ]
    ],
    "plugins": [
      "transform-object-rest-spread"
    ]
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "parser": "babel-eslint",
    "plugins": [
      "import",
      "jest"
    ],
    "parserOptions": {
      "ecmaVersion": 2017,
      "sourceType": "module"
    },
    "env": {
      "node": true,
      "jest": true
    },
    "extends": [
      "eslint:recommended"
    ]
  }
}
```

---

**Edit:**

Running the `npm config ls` command returns the following result:

> ```
> ; cli configs
> metrics-registry = "http://registry.npmjs.org/async-each"
> scope = ""
> user-agent = "npm/6.13.4 node/v12.14.0 win32 x64"
>
> ; userconfig C:\Users\username\.npmrc
> https-proxy = "http://registry.npmjs.org/"
> https://registry.npmjs.com/nodemon = ""
> key = ""
> registry = "http://registry.npmjs.org/"
> strict-ssl = false
>
> ; builtin config undefined
> prefix = "C:\\Users\\username\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm"
>
> ; node bin location = C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe
> ; cwd = H:\IRB PMX Services\core\src
> ; HOME = C:\Users\username
> ; "npm config ls -l" to show all defaults.
> ```

---

**Edit 2:**

I have now run the following command to delete the erroneous configuration key, i.e. the `https://registry.npmjs.com/nodemon = ""` part:

```
npm config delete https://registry.npmjs.com/nodemon
```

and again ran the `npm install` command. But again got the proxy error as below:

> ```
> npm ERR! network request to registry.npmjs.org/async-each/@types%2fnode failed, reason: read ECONNRESET
> npm ERR! network This is a problem related to network connectivity.
> npm ERR! network In most cases you are behind a proxy or have bad network settings.
> npm ERR! network npm ERR! network If you are behind a proxy, please make sure that the
> ...
> ```

Comment: Try running the following command to set the [registry](https://docs.npmjs.com/misc/config#registry) to the default URL, i.e. https...: `npm config set registry "https://registry.npmjs.org/"`

Comment: @RobC, again proxy error. I have tried many time this command but everytime getting proxy error.  npm ERR! network request to https://registry.npmjs.org/caniuse-lite/-/caniuse-lite-1.0.30000939.tgz failed, reason: read ECONNRESET
npm ERR! network This is a problem related to network connectivity.
npm ERR! network In most cases you are behind a proxy or have bad network settings.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I have resolved this issue with below steps :

1. make sure you have internet connection: ping 8.8.8.8
2. make sure you have DNS resolver working: ping www.google.com
3. make sure you can access registry.npmjs.org: ping registry.npmjs.org
4. make sure you can connect via https.

Run below command in npm command prompt or Visual Studio Code terminal.

`npm config rm proxy`

`npm config rm https-proxy`

Try in your browser: https://registry.npmjs.org/

Make sure you are trying to connected to:

> registry.npmjs.org

and not to:

> "registry.npmjs.org registry.npmjs.org:443"

Use below command to set registry.

`npm config set registry https://registry.npmjs.org/`

If you are using a proxy to access the Web, then you also have to configure npm to use it. Use:

`npm config set proxy http://username:password@proxyname:8080`

`npm config set https-proxy http://username:password@proxyname:8080`

Points to remember here while setting above two values :

1. proxyname you need to check with your company network team. Enter that proxy URL in above 2 values.
2. If your password contains any special character then replace it with Encoded character. In this command you can’t provide a password with special character. Replace only special character not .(dot).

   > Example: password is  : Welcome@12# then it will be like Welcome%4012%23.

https://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_urlencode.asp

Then try to run your npm install command and it should work.

Comment: What should I do if I can't ping registry.npmjs.org from my cmd or powershell?

Answer (score 4):

This fixed it for me :

`npm config delete proxy`

`npm config delete http-proxy`

`npm config delete https-proxy`

Happy coding !

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I have just use these commands to solve my problem for npm proxy bad  setting and npm proxy errors 7:14am 19|dec|23

```
npm config delete proxy
npm config delete http-proxy
npm config delete https-proxy
```