# Tried creating a new react app but I keep getting this error. I have tried cleaning cache (npm), uninstalled create-react-app(global). Any solution?

Tags: reactjs, npm

[screenshot from my terminal showing error after I ran (npx create-react-app )](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LqtwB.png)

Comment: take a look at this : https://stackoverflow.com/a/60435761/9869240

Comment: ooops! still not working

Answer (score 0):

For some reason, npm is unable to download the necessary packages.
It could be due to:

- Bad internet connection
- Firewall blocking the traffic
- You are behind a proxy.

Anycase, you can inspect `npm-debug.log` to check what happened.

Comment: didn't work for me but thanks. I got it fixed

Answer (score 0):

For long, I've tried all the answers in stack overflow but nothing worked. The only solution that worked for me is;

```
deleting .npmrc file in Users/you/.npmrc
```

I figured out npm might be corrupt and since .npmrc is the configuration file that defines the settings on how NPM should behave when running commands, it needs to be deleted as I understood this documentation  https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v8/configuring-npm/npmrc/