# when Im trying to install react i get this error how to fix it and install react

Tags: javascript, reactjs

npm ERR! code ENOTFOUND
npm ERR! syscall getaddrinfo
npm ERR! errno ENOTFOUND
npm ERR! network request to http://registry.npmjs.org/create-react-app failed, reason: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND your_proxy_url
npm ERR! network This is a problem related to network connectivity.
npm ERR! network In most cases you are behind a proxy or have bad network settings.
npm ERR! network
npm ERR! network If you are behind a proxy, please make sure that the
npm ERR! network 'proxy' config is set properly.  See: 'npm help config'

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in: C:\Users\Arani\AppData\Local\npm-cache_logs\2024-01-09T00_57_25_359Z-debug-0.log

i want a command to mitigate this issue

Comment: Seems because you're behind a proxy: `If you are behind a proxy, please make sure that the network 'proxy' config is set properly.`
So try these proxy-related solutions: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60037937/how-to-resolve-npm-proxy-issue-whilel-running-node-js-application.

Comment: try one od these: 1 check internet connection. 2. disable proxy 3. if you run proxy make sure proxy configuration is correct 4. try to reinstall it

Answer (score 1):

The error message indicates a problem with network connectivity, suggesting that npm is unable to connect to the npm registry. This can be due to a proxy issue or general network problems. Here are a few steps you can take to resolve this:

**Check your internet connection:**

**Disable the proxy (if you are not behind a proxy):**

If you are not behind a proxy, you may need to disable it in your npm configuration. Run the following command to disable the proxy settings:

```
npm config rm proxy
npm config rm https-proxy
```

**Set the proxy (if you are behind a proxy):**

If you are behind a proxy, make sure to set the correct proxy configurations using the following commands:

```
npm config set proxy http://your_proxy_url
npm config set https-proxy http://your_proxy_url
```

**Retry the installation:**

After making the necessary changes, try running the installation command again:

```
npm install -g create-react-app
```

If you are creating a new React app, you can use:

```
npx create-react-app your-app-name
```

If the issue persists, you may need to investigate further based on your specific network environment and configurations. Additionally, you can review the detailed log file mentioned in the error message (C:\Users\Arani\AppData\Local\npm-cache_logs\2024-01-09T00_57_25_359Z-debug-0.log) for more information on the error and possible solutions.

Comment: thank you so much i have been trying to fix this for so long it dint work, its all good  now

Comment: @AraniAravinthan which step was it that fixed your problem? Disabling the proxy, setting the proxy configuration, or retrying the installation?